# Windows Phone - Web client request doesn't get executed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

/* While writing this question , and testing stuff , i managed to answer the question, I'm sharing my findings so they would be of help to some other poor soul. Please see answer below. */

I'm trying to fetch a JSON data from my API in a background task.
I have the background task nice and running doing it's thing , but when i try to get the data , nothing happens ?!?

here is the code i use :

```
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {

        string wurl = @"http://test.com/api/stuff/getdata";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(wurl));


        NotifyComplete();

    }
```

and that's all ... the `webClient_DownloadStringCompleted` never gets executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key thing here is that the `WebClient` executes its method ***asynchronously*** and `NotifyComplete()`  gets executed before the `WebClient` has the chance to fetch the data.

When you call `NotifyComplete()` , it notifies the OS that you are done executing your task and the system should terminate it.

The solution is to move `NotifyComplete()` at the end of the async method `webClient_DownloadStringCompleted` ( in this case) and ... voala !

***Warning 1:*** You have up to 25 seconds to finish whatever you are doing , otherwise the task gets terminated.

***Warning 2:*** Your background task cannot consume more than (on some phones ) 6 MB (on the emulator i tested with windows phone 8) 10 MB of memory! if your background task does , it will be terminated.

It's good to consider using Resource Intensive background task if your app is going to consume more memory and time ( up to 10 minutes) , note this type of task is only available while the phone is charging!